# Prevent fetching reference table values while using entityframework

Tags: entity-framework

I am using EntityFramework in my Apllication. If I want to fetch one table value means that will return values with all the referenced table values. It takes time to fetch all the table values. If I need one specified reference table values means

How do I Prevent fetching  other reference table values?

Comment: What does _values_ mean? Rows? Columns? Navigation Properties? Something else?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extract single table record without reference tables so you need to define LazyLoadingEnabled false in your DBContext class.

**Example your database name is EmpReview**

```
public class UserDataLayerContext : DbContext
{
    public UserDataLayerContext()
        : base("name=EmpReview")
    {
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    }
```

So all the DBSet classes which in UserDataLayerContext filter time only get the single table record without any reference class.

Using this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false; none of return reference table calss but in that you need to get single reference table check below example,

Suppose one table class is UserMaster and it is link to GroupMaster master

```
So 
return context.UserMasters.Include("GroupMaster").Where(x => (x.UserID == id) && (x.IsActive == 
        true)).ToList();
```

In that case you get all the usermaster record with group master table.

And

```
return context.UserMasters.Where(x => (x.UserID == id) && (x.IsActive == true)).ToList();
```

above case you get all the record of usermaster with out group master table.

Comment: Is there any option to fetch only two reference table values instead of fetching all the reference all table values.,how to customize fetching particular reference table values to speed up the execution